# Is this normal (low area below front of 2002 Honda Odyssey)?

Tags: honda, odyssey

I'm no car expert, so forgive me. But on my family's 2002 Honda Odyssey, I've noticed for some time that when viewing the front of the van from a little distance, it appears as though some material under the left side front of the bottom of the van appears to hang or be positioned lower than the rest. This hasn't affected use of the car, but I find it concerning. Is this normal?

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Yes that is too low. Several of the plastic fasteners are missing. For example in the third picture the hole in the white bumper is empty and the contact ring left from when it was installed is visible.  91506-S9A-003 is a typical part number for this application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the shredded plastic and rust I'm seeing, it looks like someone scraped the bottom pretty good. If it's still operating fine and not leaking it's probably nothing to worry about, but have a mechanic give it a good once-over to be safe.

Regardless, yes, it looks like the splash guard (the broad plastic piece also known as a rock guard) is hanging lower on the left than it should be. You can confirm by crawling underneath and pushing up on it. If all is well it shouldn't move very much.

If it is hanging, it's hard to tell why. It may just be a missing screw, it may be the plastic is too badly mangled to be properly secured. Either way I'd see about getting it sorted out. If you need to get a new guard, used ones can be had on ebay or a local scrap yard. If you need a temporary solution, some holes in the plastic and zip-ties will get you by.